# find the canonical form of the hyperbolic PDE $a(x, y)u_{xx} + 2b(x, y)u_{xy} + c(x, y)u_{yy} + F(x, y,u,u_x,u_y)= 0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, canonical-transformation

So the question is trying to transform in the hyperbolic case, the PDE

$$a(x, y)u_{xx} + 2b(x, y)u_{xy} + c(x, y)u_{yy} + F(x, y,u,u_x,u_y)= 0$$

can be transformed to the normal form

$$\widetilde{u}_{ξ\eta} + {\Psi}(ξ, \eta , \widetilde{u}, \widetilde{u}_ξ,\widetilde{u}_η)$$

I know the steps I need to follow for this. However I don't know how to apply certain ones. For instance what does F represent in this case. Where would it fall in the general second order PDE. For example, here A = a, B = 2b, and C = 1. Am I on the right track? I just need to know what each constant is and how to deal with F and I can move forward from there.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: $F$ is just a function of the lower order terms in the equation, which have no bearing on the transformation to canonical form. Hence, it doesn't matter what the form of $F$ is. And yes, your reading off of the coefficients $A,B,C$ is correct, provided the characteristics are given by $B^{2} - \color{red}4 AC$. [The characteristics can be defined differently though](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_differential_equation#Linear_equations_of_second_order), such as $B^{2} - AC$, in which case $B = b$. But that is just a definition.

Comment: Thank you I have proceeded with that but I am facing a problem now. I reached a point where I got the $u_{xx}$ and $u_{yy}$  and $u_{xy}$ but when i plug them in the PDE I face some problems. First the $u_{xx}$ will be multiplied by a, $u_{yy}$ by 2b, and  $u_{xy}$ by 1. But then I don't see myself being able to cancel anything out. Especially since my η = $y - x(2b-1)/a$. Do you have any hints for this?

Comment: I think you should follow the notes on page 37 [here](http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~kersale/Teach/M3414/Notes/m3414_1.pdf).

Comment: @mattos so does this mean that A=1, B=2, C=1 or am I missing something?